# CodeIgniter - Associating two different data come from DB into a paragraph in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter, replace

I am trying to get unit and staff count using

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(unit_id)
        FROM
            tbl_units) AS uCount,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(staff_id)
        FROM
            tbl_staff) AS sCount
```

For example, the result might be

```
uCount | sCount
----------------
     5 |      45
```

And the text comes

```
SELECT title, text FROM tbl_content WHERE alias = 'about'
```

Retrieved result

> employees at units work in our company...

I want to put those value into a paragraph. I send both data to view

```
$this->load->view('about', array('text' => $text, 'sCount' => $sCount, 'uCount' => $uCount));
```

The result should be like:

> 45 employees at 5 units work in our company

My idea is putting variable names into text's itself and replace them. So text would be like:

> $1 employees at $2 units work in our company

after getting text using `str_replace()` would be useful.

But I want to know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the variable names inside double quotes and php will parse it.

eg:

```
echo "{$sCount} employees at {$uCount} units work in our company";
```

Comment: Could you give us the result you get?

Comment: I get the following result: `{$sCount} employees at {$uCount} units work in our company` no substitution

Comment: you must use duble quotes, like this: <?php echo "some text {$var}";?>

Comment: I understand, but I do not see the text I get text in a variable `$text`. I go with `str_replace()`

Answer (score 0):

Code I have written in CodeIgnitor is as below :

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $sCount = 45;
    $uCount = 5;
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', array('sCount' => $sCount, 'uCount' => $uCount));
}
```

**view**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    ::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
    }

    a {
        color: #003399;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #444;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 14px 0;
        padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
    }

    code {
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        color: #002166;
        display: block;
        margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
        padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    }

    #body {
        margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    }

    p.footer {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        line-height: 32px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    #container {
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
    <div id="body">
        <p><?php echo "{$sCount} employees at {$uCount} units work in our company";?></p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it will resolve your problem